# How do you authenticate with XOAUTH using SMTP with Rails 3 ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, oauth-2.0, gmail, actionmailer

I'm trying to send out mail from a gmail account using action_mailer smtp. I've obtained the OAUTH2 access_token, but I'm not sure where to enter this in the SMTP settings. Here's my current smtp_settings hash:

```
{
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :user_name => 'email@example.com',
  :password => [NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE AS WE ARE NOT USING A PASSWORD],
  :authentication => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Should I be setting the 'authentication' key to 'XOAUTH'? Where do I put the access_token to authenticate with gmail?
Thanks for your help!